# three.js outline does not work when scene set `scene.background=texture`

Tags: three.js

I caeate outline according to this example https://threejs.org/examples/?q=out#webgl_postprocessing_outline.And this is the result.It is works well.[image]But when i set `scene.background=texture`,it is not work.IAnd i check the `three.js` document about `scene.background`. (If not null, sets the background used when rendering the scene, and is always rendered first. Can be set to a Color which sets the clear color, a Texture covering the canvas, or a CubeTexture. Default is null).I want to find out why outline disappear.[image]Here is the code.

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var light, floor;
var WIDTH,HEIGHT;
var controls;
var composer;
var composer, effectFXAA, outlinePass;
WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
init();
animation()
function init () {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textureLoader.load('img/bg.png', function(texture){
        scene.background = texture;
    });
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH/HEIGHT, 0.1, 800);
camera.position.set(0,150,150);
scene.add(camera);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff));
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
controls = new OrbitControls(camera);
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(0,4);
shape.lineTo(0,96);
shape.lineTo(4,100);
shape.lineTo(96,100);
shape.lineTo(100,96);
shape.lineTo(100,4);
shape.lineTo(96, 0 );
shape.lineTo(84,0);
shape.lineTo(80,4);
shape.lineTo(20, 4);
shape.lineTo(16, 0);
shape.lineTo(4, 0 );
shape.lineTo(0, 4);
            var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x0E2350 } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
            mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
            mesh.translateX(-50);
            mesh.translateY(-50);
            scene.add(mesh);

            composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
            var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
            composer.addPass( renderPass );
            outlinePass = new THREE.OutlinePass( new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), scene, camera );
            outlinePass.edgeStrength = 3;
            outlinePass.edgeGlow = 3.0;
            outlinePass.edgeThickness = 0.1;
            outlinePass.visibleEdgeColor.setHex(0x19C0EE);
            composer.addPass( outlinePass );
            effectFXAA = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FXAAShader );
            effectFXAA.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.set( 1 / window.innerWidth, 1 / window.innerHeight );
            effectFXAA.renderToScreen = true;
            composer.addPass( effectFXAA );
            outlinePass.selectedObjects = [mesh];
        }
        function animation() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animation);
            composer.render();
            render();
            controls.update();

        };
        function render () {
            renderer.render(scene, camera)
        };
```